# Voltage appears on comparator input

Tags: comparator, schmitt-trigger

[image]

I have made a pcb . 
A part of the circuit is  the  Schmitt trigger   comparator seen above .
The  positive feedback resistors are chosen to give the noniverting input  values from zero to 0.5 volts . 
 The inverting input will receive pulses of around 300mV amplitude and 20 ns width , but   while the amplifier isn't connected anywhere (yet)   a voltage of 1.1 volt appears on the pin  . Any ideas why that happens ?

Comment: It's not clear why you regard this 1.1V value you measure on the inverting input to be a problem. What are you expecting to measure here and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not leave an input pin floating! It is not designed to be used like that.

What you could do is add a 1 Mohm resistor between the - input pin and ground. At least then there is some defined voltage on the pin.

But when the input is **floating**, its voltage is determined by the internal circuit on the IC. Unfortunately, in the [datasheet of the AD8611](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad8611_8612.pdf), there is no internal schematic so we can only **guess** what is there.

Typically these type of inputs consist of a base (or gate) of a differential pair. Also some ESD protection (often diodes) are connected. All these devices will have some leakage current. Even a small leakage current will produce some voltage across the high input resistance (often 10 Mohm) of your multimeter.

For fun you could also measure between the VCC and - input, you might expect to see 5.0 V - 1.1 V = 3.9 V right? But that's only true if the 1.1 V you measured at the - input is a "hard/strong" voltage (like there's a 1.1 V voltage source in the IC). My guess is that you will not measure 3.9 V between VCC and - input. What you will measure depends on the leakage current that is going to flow.

Answer (score 4):

You're relying on unspecified behaviour, so undefined behaviour happens. A floating input does exactly that: float. The tiniest influence can pull it anywhere.

Physically, opamps are chips, and there's bound to be some capacitive coupling between the inputs.

I also doubt you're able to actually measure the actual voltage: A multimeter typically has lower impedance (or at least in the same order) than a high-Z opamp input. In the case of an AD8611, the input bias current is lower in magnitude than -6 µA.

So, if you don't want an input to float, don't let it float. Use high-valued resistors to tie it to either ground or VCC, whichever level you prefer. Based on the -6 µA bias current, some 470 kΩ should work.

BTW, when building something like this, use a comparator, not an OPamp; while the same in theory, you can get latch-up behaviour with Opamps that you wouldn't see in comparators; also, comparators can be had for much higher bandwidths cheaply.

If you need a Schmitt trigger receiver, then use a Schmitt trigger receiver; LVDS receiver ICs do pretty much what you built.